# How to edit Extjs5 responsive-app example project with eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, extjs5

I want to create a responsive app with Extjs5. I found a perfect example  in sencha documentation which would fit perfectly for start. I unsuccessfully tried to import example project copy to my eclipse workbench by simply copying it to my Maven project...

When I try to view my project I just see a white page and these errors appear:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:.../bootstrap.json. Cross origin
>    requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>    chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

I was able to modify project using external folder link, but when I remove example from ext-5.1.0 folder it just stops working and the same white page on the browser screen shows.

So my question is :

How to import this demo http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/responsive-app/index.html to my workbench that I could easily edit it with eclipse ?

Comment: What have you already tried?  What errors are you getting? You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run any demo example from `sencha` SDK downloaded zip..

1) Just go to specific example directory from `command prompt`

2) Execute command '`sencha app watch`'

3) Now move on to your browser and enter URL **localhost:1841**